# How to apply rigid body animation to frame 1 in Blender 2.81

Tags: animation, rigid-body-simulation

I am trying to create a Pool Game animation. I have managed to create this so far - [Animation](https://youtu.be/1dx0U8EswaM)
I am using rigid body physics to simulate the game and animating the cue ball. I has worked well, but after I try to animate the cue ball for the 3rd time, the entire set of balls is messed up and rigid body simulation does not give the same result as the last frame of my finished animation.

Is there a way to reset the world, apply the transforms to all the balls from simulation at frame 1 and start animating the cue ball for every shot?

Is there any other way to finish this animation and pot all the balls?

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution after searching for hours-

https://blenderartists.org/t/locking-down-freezing-rigid-body-positions-after-sim/591104/10?u=bharat_justa

[image]